# why instaling type-graphql, @apollo/server and graphql together showing dependency error

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

I have been trying to install typegraphql with apollo/server in typescript node template but it showing dependency error, I don't know why all new version is not compatible with each other.

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: server@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: graphql@16.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   graphql@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer graphql@"^16.6.0" from @apollo/server@4.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@apollo/server
npm ERR!     @apollo/server@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! type-graphql@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: graphql@15.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   peer graphql@"^15.3.0" from type-graphql@1.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/type-graphql
npm ERR!     type-graphql@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.



$ npm i @apollo/server express graphql reflect-metadata type-graphql
```

should forcing it works or will it lead to data-leaks and all?
Thanks in advance for replying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most recent version of `type-graphql` only works with `graphql` version `^15.5.0`. Almost all newer versions of `@apollo/server` and graphql-related libraries, on the other hand, only support `graphql` version `>= 16`.
Fortunately, a newer version of `type-graphql` (version `2.0.0`), which is still in **beta**, is available under the `next` tag version in `npm`.
To install it, first uninstall `type-graphql` and then reinstall it specifying the `next` tag:

```bash
npm uninstall type-graphql
npm install type-graphql@next
```

PS: If you want to look at a working example project, check out [this](https://github.com/carlocorradini/reCluster/tree/main/server).